# What does “flunked vacation and flunked relaxing" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Today’s Washington Post (May 10) portrays what the SEAL who shot bin Laden looks like under the headline,. “Who shot bin Laden? Former SEALs fill in the blank.”

In this article, former Navy SEALs Richard Marcinko and Stew Smith guess the shooter must be “a positive thinker” who “gets in trouble when he’s not challenged,” Richard Marcinko suspects, a man who “flunked vacation and flunked relaxing.”

I was interested in the expression, the guy “gets in trouble when he’s not challenged,” because I’m not that kind, but caught up with the word, flunk in “flunked vacation and flunked relaxing.”

My understanding of the meaning of “flunk” was only “fail in exam or work.” So I checked the meaning of “flunk” in Oxford Advanced Learner’s Dictionary, which simply defines “flunk” as an intransitive verb meaning “to fail an exam or test or course, and to make sb fail an exam or course by giving a low mark or grade as transitive verb. The definition doesn’t sit well with vacation and relaxing.

Does “flunk” here mean dislike or ignore? Is this popular way of using “flunk” in day- to-day English?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a joke: "Flunk" is being used as you understand it ("to fail") but in a humorous way. Marcinko is saying that if the shooter tried to relax, he would be unable to, because he is addicted to his work.